# CallKit ,when to use reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason:

Tags: callkit

In my practice, I found that the Answer can also end a call with reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason:, but as we know , we should end a call with requestTransaction of ExEndCallAction, so what's the difference between them, when should we use reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason: and what dose it do for us!

Answer (score 3):

You do `requestTransaction` with a `CXEndCallAction` when the user actively chooses to end the call from your app's UI.

You do `reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason:` when it ended not due to user action (i.e. not due to `provider:performEndCallAction:`). If you take a look at the allowed `CXCallEndedReason`s (failed, remote ended, unanswered, answered elsewhere, and declined elsewhere), they are all reasons not due to the user's action.

Comment: thanks, but in which situation should we explicitly call reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason?  can you take some examples?

Comment: @foolishBoy: I have already listed the reasons above. i.e. Call failed, other side ended (declined call or ended call that was ongoing), unanswered (timed out with no answer from other side), answered by you on another device, declined by you on another device. Basically, you should use it in any situation where the call ended not due to the user manually pressing an "end" or "decline" button in your app or in CallKit.

Comment: thanks very much, I thought we should requestTransaction with a CXEndCallAction for above reasons.  so, I mixed up these end method, but I don't found any bug, can you explain that?

Comment: @foolishBoy: Well they both accomplish the same thing -- end the call from the perspective of CallKit. I don't think there's much actual difference in behavior between the user ending it or if it's ended by some other reason. The difference between the two APIs is that reporting that a call ended definitely ends the call, whereas for requesting an transaction, the system could reject your transaction; but I don't think a single end call action can ever get rejected, so in practice it's the same.

Comment: It's better to use reportCallWithUUID method for the above reasons because the transaction may get rejected with an error com.apple.callkit.error.requesttransaction code=4, which means different UUID is used to end the call than the one used to start.